# When to call flush() and commit() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following case:

```
        openSession()

        tx = session.beginTransaction();

    try
    {
        ...
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj_1);
        ...
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj_2);
        ...
        session.saveOrUpdate(obj_3);

        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
    }
    catch()
    {
       tx.rollback()
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
```

The first call of **saveOrUpdate(obj_1)** will failed due to ***Duplicate entry*** error. But this error would not actually happen until the database is accessed at the end of the **session.flush()**.

Is there a way to make this kind of error happens early and give me more chance to correctly handle it?

I also don't want to cut the transaction too small because it is hard to rollback.

My Hibernate entities are reversed from an existing database schema.

I have disabled the cache in my configuration file:

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
```

**EDIT:**

My question is how can I get the error as early as possible if any. The error itself doesn't matter to me.

Right now the error happens at the end, but it actually happened at the first access.

Comment: hello @5YrsLaterDBA   are you getting some error here ,if yes then please include stack-trace with your question,which would be really helpful in identifying actual cause of your error.

Comment: I am not asking how to avoid error. So error message is irrelevant here. What I am asking is how to make Hibernate throw error back as early as possible and I can handle it early.

Comment: ok as you said in your question"The first call of saveOrUpdate(obj_1) will failed due to Duplicate entry error. But this error would not actually happen until the database is accessed at the end of the session.flush()" but as per my practical knowledge tells me  if you have defined any field as unique constrain and b'cos of some resone it is getting violated you will get  org.hibernate.HibernateException while  session.saveOrUpdate

Answer (score 2):

You can execute `session.flush()` after each `session.saveOrUpdate` to force hibernate to execute the update or insert on your database. Without the flush command the actual database operations are deferred and will only be processed immediately before ending the transaction.

This way you don't have to change the size of your transaction.

Comment: This may be the solution. But what's the down side for this frequently flush() call? First-level cache or Second-level cache is downgrade? I tested, I know the flush() will NOT actually touch the physical database.

Comment: How did you test the access to the physical database? There is no commit, so you can't see any changes when you use any query tool.

Comment: That is why I said the flush() will not update the physical database until the tx.commit() is called. And the flush() will cause error if there is any, so I am thinking the Hibernate must did something somewhere. It must be one of the cache then.

Comment: flush() causes the sql operations to be executed, and if there is something wrong it gets an error code from the underlying database. This does change the database, but this change is only visible inside the current session, unless the isolation level is READ_UNCOMMITTED. So there are two steps to change the global database state, flush() (execute insert or update) and commit() (ending the transaction).

Answer (score -2):

You can execute  Surendran after each session.saveOrUpdate to force hibernate to execute the update or insert on your database. Without the flush command the actual database operations are deferred and will only be processed immediately before ending the transaction.

This way you don't have to change the size of your transaction.